# How to move a rectangle to the top left of another rotated and translated rectangle?

Tags: javascript, math, matrix

Suppose I have following matrices for `Rect1` and `Rect2`,

```
Rect1 = [
    0.707, 0.707, 0, 0, 
    -0.707, 0.707, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1
]

Rect2 = [
    0.707, 0.707, 0, 0, 
    -0.707, 0.707, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 
    200, 200, 0, 1
]
```

`Rect1` and `Rect2` are both to 45 degrees. `Rect2` is translated to `(200, 200)`. Rect1 has a height of `20px` and width of `20px`. `Rect2` has a height of `200px` and width of `300px`.

In a canvas they look like following,

[image]

Now, how do I calculate the position for `Rect1` to be positioned to the top left of `Rect1` so that it looks like following,

[image]

Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-driscoll-ws8q1

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate both images, the rectangle block becomes approx. 354 x 354 and little square id approx. 28 x 28.  So the top tip of the bigger rectangle is displaced by 106px and then add 200px for translation. So its position from left is 306px.  Similarly from top it is displaced by -71px and then 200px translation.  So it is at 129px.  So your smaller rectangle position can bi displaced like this.

```
const box2Node = {
  node: document.getElementById("box2"),
  matrix: matrixIdentity(),
  height: 20,
  width: 20,
  settings() {
    return [1, angle, [306, 129]];
  }
};
```

Comment: How are you calculating all this?

Comment: Not exactly sure.. As I mentioned the eventual big one becomes - 354 x 354. So top juts up by roughly -77px.  [(354 - 300)/2].  And then add 200px for translation. That gives 123px. And similarly the smaller one is 28 x 28. And that would jut up by -4px. Similar calculations from left as well. Though these may not be 100% accurate.